# Find the sum of the coefficients in the expansion of $(3x^2 + x -2)^{2017}$

Tags: polynomials

To find the sum of the coefficients in the given multinomial expansion, need take all powers of the coefficients, while the variable $x$ terms are ignored.

So, $(3x^2 + 1.x -2)^{2017}= (3 + 1 -2)^{2017}  = 2^{2017}$

Request vetting, & any alternate approach too.

Comment: `while the variable x terms are ignored` Better wording is that the sum of the coefficients of a polynomial $\,P(x)\,$ is simply $\,P(1)=\ldots\,$. Other than that, yes, that's the way to solve it.

Comment: @dxiv Thanks for improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree,
because,
if
$f(x)
=(3x^2 + x -2)^{2017}
=\sum_{k=0}^m a_kx^k
$
(whatever $m$ might be),
then
$\sum_{k=0}^m a_k
=\sum_{k=0}^m a_k(1)^k
=f(1)
=(3(1)^2 + 1 -2)^{2017}
=2^{2017}
$.